# Definable over $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$

Tags: model-theory

I have the following task and I am not so sure about my solution:

a) Is $\{0\}$ definable over $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$?

b) Is $\{1\}$ definable over $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$?

c) Is $<$ definable over $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$?

So I have to give a formula, using only the symbols of the modell, for $\{0\}$, $\{1\}$ and $<$.

a) My try is the following:

$\varphi\equiv\forall v_0(v_0+v_1=v_0)$

This should be only true, if $v_1=0$

b)

$\varphi\equiv\forall v_0(v_0\cdot v_1=v_0)$

and c)

$\varphi\equiv ((v_0+(v_1\cdot v_1)=v_2)\wedge (v_1+v_1\neq v_1))$

The second condition $(v_1+v_1\neq v_1)$ excludes the possibilty of $v_1=0$.
Since I add $v_1\cdot v_1$, which is positiv, this formula should state, that $v_0<v_2$

Unfortunatly I am not sure, if I solved this task adequate, and would be thankfull for your opinion.

Tanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the existential quantifier for $v_{1}$ in (c)?

Comment: You are right. If I write it without the existential quantifier, it is not necessarly right, so I have to give the formula

$\varphi\equiv \exists v_1 ((v_0+(v_1\cdot v_1)=v_2)\wedge (v_1+v_1\neq v_1))$

Comment: Yes, that's all.

Comment: Thank you, Isaac Solomon and Berci. That was really fast. :)